# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I'm using tensorflow for the first time and amusing it to classify data with 18 features into 4 classes.

The dimensions of X_train are: (14125,18).

This is my code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array(X_train.values, dtype=float),
                               np.array(y_train.pet_category.values, dtype=float)))
train_data = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(32)

vdataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array(X_val.values, dtype=float)))
val_data = vdataset.batch(32)

tfmodel = tf.keras.Sequential([
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(18,1)),
                  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

tfmodel.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

On calling `tfmodel.fit(dataset, epochs=15, validation_data=val_data)`, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 270 but received input with shape [18, 15]
```

I tried looking for similar questions but couldn't find anything that'd help. Would be really helpful to solve this issue

Edit: The issue was with the version. It went away when I used a lower version of TensorFlow (v 2.1.0).

Comment: Your input shape should be `(18,)` if the shape of your data is `(14125,18)` in which I'm assuming 14125 is the number of datapoints.

Comment: Tried it out, the error changed to `Input 0 of layer sequential is... input shape to have value 18 but received input with shape [18, 1]`

Comment: Can you just try `train_data.element_spec` and see the shape of your dataset?

Comment: `(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 18), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))`

Comment: Um can you try with `input_shape=(18)` since your dataset shape is also the same?

Comment: Input shape requires a tuple so that doesn't work. It just says int is not iterable

Comment: Ideally, when you are feeding input to `Dense`, it should have a shape `(shape,)` which in your case is `(18,)`, so that should have worked.

Comment: Oh wait the error probably might be in the `Flatten` layer. Since you are already getting an output of shape `(batch_size, 18)` in your case, you don't need to flatten it out. You can remove the  `Flatten` layer and it should work I guess

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work, `ValueError: Shapes () and (18, 1, 4) are incompatible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was with the version of tensorflow I was using (2.3.0)
I tried with the nightly build and it gave the same error.
I downgraded to v2.1.0 and it worked

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `dataset` int `fit` instead of `train_data`. I assume you are using a DataFrame called `X_train` and `y_train` and I mimicked the same with numpy and it works now. See below.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.random((14125,18))
y_train = np.random.random((14125,1))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_data = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(32)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(
        buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

tfmodel = tf.keras.Sequential([
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(18,)),
                  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

tfmodel.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

tfmodel.fit(train_data, epochs=5)
```

Note: I didn't use the `val_data`

```
Train for 442 steps
Epoch 1/5
442/442 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 7.8375 - accuracy: 1.4159e-04
Epoch 2/5
442/442 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 28.5034 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
442/442 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 17.8604 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
442/442 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4244 - accuracy: 2.1239e-04
Epoch 5/5
442/442 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 3.2791 - accuracy: 0.0160
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f0d8c72d630>
```

Comment: Oh wow I did make that mistake. Would've been an issue later on. But seems like it still doesn't work. I tried to run your code and it gave the same error

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: I'm using `tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0`